# SQL Server: How to generate object scripts without DMO/SMO?

Tags: sql-server, scripting, sql-server-2000, ddl

i want to generate scripts for database objects, e.g.

- tables
- views
- stored procedures
- functions

Since:

- [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)
- [SQL Distributed Management Objects (SQL-DMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131540.aspx) (depricated)

are not installed on a fresh install of:

- Windows XP
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7

nor are they redistributable, they are not an option (*it will run on a customer's machine*).

(**EDIT**: It looks as if SMO is actually [redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8824#QuickInfoContainer) as of today.)

Is there any source code that converts **SELECTs** from **system tables** into associated scripts?

---

i'll start us off with the **pseudo-code** that scripts a stored procedures, views, triggers, or user-defined functions:

```
String GetStoredProcedureScript(String storedProcedureName)
{
   return GetHelpText(storedProcedureName);
}

String GetViewScript(String viewName)
{
   return GetHelpText(viewName);
}

String GetTriggerScript(String triggerName)
{
   return GetHelpText(storedProcedureName);
}

String GetUserDefinedFunctionScript(String userDefinedFunctionName)
{
   return GetHelpText(userDefinedFunctionName);
}
```

All which can internally use a single helper function:

```
String GetHelpText(String objectName)
{
   String szQuery = 'EXECUTE sp_helptext '+QuotedStr(objectName);


   String sql := '';

   using (Recordset rs = connection.Execute(szQuery))
   {
      while not rs.EOF do
      {
         sql = sql+rs['text'];
         rs.Next;
      }
   }

   return sql;
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks [servicesharvest316](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804408/sql-server-how-to-generate-object-scripts-without-dmo-smo/1877134#1877134) for pointing out `sp_helptext`. That's why i have a class that abstracts these things away.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is the book for you.  It explains how to make a code generator that will do what you asked.

I use a modified version for MySql and it worked like a charm.
[Code Generation in Microsoft .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590591372)

Comment: Can you give us a hint of the techniques?

Comment: This is a multi step process.
1- You have to read the metadata from the database (Table, columns, PKey, FKey, Restrictions if you want security). There is always a system table with the data in MySQL the database for that is Information_Schema.  
2- You have to make youre template of a typical class in XSLT
3- If you want tyou can add a FreeForm XML
4- Mash up all this and you'll have a complete class

I don't have it with me but I could send you my project if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sp_helptext?

```
String szQuery = 'EXEC sp_helptext '+QuotedStr(storedProcedureName)
```

Comment: Thanks for sp_helptext. That makes everything done, except tables.

Answer (score 0):

[Open DBDiff](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenDBiff) (referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377388/are-there-any-free-alternatives-to-red-gates-tools-like-sql-compare)) implements a GUI for comparing databases and generating an update script. It also includes a command line tool. You could use the guts of the project to generate CREATE TABLE statements.