# Change the ANSI_NULLS setting for all Stored Procedures in the Database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have some problems with the ANSI_NULLS setting and computed columns and we have a ton of stored procedures that have

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

We want to change them all to

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

Is there an easy way to do that or must I extract all the SPs to a script, change it and run it again to drop and recreate all the SPa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must script all the procedures, and re-create them with ANSI_NULLS on.

If i had *a lot* to do, i might add a function to my client app.

PseudoCode:

```
procedure FixAllStoredProcedureAnsiNullness(connection)
{
   Strings spNames = GetStoredProcedureNames(connection);

   foreach spName in spNames
   {
       String sql = GetStoredProcedureSQL(connection, spName);

       //turn on option for remainder of connection
       connection.ExecuteNoRecords("SET ANSI_NULLS ON"); 

       BeginTransaction(connection);
       try
          connection.ExecuteNoRecords("DROP PROCEDURE "+spName);
          connection.ExecuteNoRecords(sql);
          CommitTranasction(connection);
       except
          RollbackTransaction(connection);
          raise;
       end;
   }
}
```

i had code on how to get the SQL of a stored procedure programatically on [SQL Server: How to generate object scripts without DMO/SMO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804408/sql-server-how-to-generate-object-scripts-without-dmo-smo)

But normally i'll just use **Enterprise Manager**, starting at the top of the stored procedure list:

1. <kbd>Return</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
4. Click OK
5. <kbd>Down</kbd>
6. Goto 1

Where my clipboard contains:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
```

If you're unfortunate enough to be stuck with SSMS, then you're SOL with that POS, IIRC.  TWSS.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will go that way using this Sql to get all failing SPs and their code:

select object_name(object_id) as Name, definition as Code
from sys.all_sql_modules
where objectproperty([object_id], 'IsProcedure') = 1 and uses_ansi_nulls = 0

Comment: I just added the C# code to recreate all sps :) we cant do it by hand because we have 8 databases and near 500 on each one so thanks for point out how to automatize the process.

Comment: Edited pseudo-code: set ansi_nulls option once on the connection - since a "CREATE PROC" must be alone in the batch.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that we use was the posted by **Ian** and now we have an automated procedure to solve the problem.

Here is the final code that we use to recreate all the SPs from the database:

```
public static class AnsiNullsManager
{

    public static void ReCreateAllStoredProcedures(SqlConnection connection, bool ansiNullsOn)
    {
        var sql =
            @"select object_name(sys.all_sql_modules.object_id) as Name, definition as Code
                from sys.all_sql_modules inner join sys.objects ON 
                sys.all_sql_modules.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
                where objectproperty(sys.all_sql_modules.object_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 AND is_ms_shipped = 0 and uses_ansi_nulls = " +
            (ansiNullsOn ? "0" : "1") +
            "ORDER BY Name ";

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        var sps = new List<SpObject>();

        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sps.Add(new SpObject(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)));
            }
        }

        var cmdSetAnsiNulls = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmdSetAnsiNulls.CommandText = "SET ANSI_NULLS " + (ansiNullsOn ? "ON" : "OFF") + ";";
        cmdSetAnsiNulls.ExecuteNonQuery();

        foreach (var sp in sps)
        {
            var trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {

                var cmdDrop = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmdDrop.CommandText = "DROP PROCEDURE " + sp.Name;
                cmdDrop.Transaction = trans;
                cmdDrop.ExecuteNonQuery();



                var cmdReCreate = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmdReCreate.CommandText = sp.Code;
                cmdReCreate.Transaction = trans;
                cmdReCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trans.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }

    }

    private class SpObject
    {
        public SpObject(string name, string code)
        {
            Name = name;
            Code = code;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Code { get; private set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to throw a warning in there.  I can't imagine why you had ansi_nulls set off for ALL your SPs but if any of them were counting on comparisons to NULL in any way (and there can be a lot of different ways that could happen) your results will different when you change that setting.  I recommend some rigorous regression testing in a safe environment.

Comment: @TG: Thanks for that warning, all these store procedures are CRUD operations auto generated. We have all SPs with that option because we left in the template sql the SET ANSI_NULLS OFF. The procedures are so simple that we don't get into this problem.

Comment: I see - that makes sense.  If your code generator had that ansi_nulls setting then of course they would all end up that way.  Then likely any manually created SPs will have not have ansi_nulls turned off.  I guess the only potential "gottcha" would if any of the generated SP had JOINs on nullable columns.  But it doesn't sound like that's the case.  Carry on :)

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way is to script the s'procs, run find and replace command, then run the proc definitions again.

Comment: It's not the easiest way when you have hundreds of stored procedures.